# Sharepoint Only - Child List using Parent List Columns

Tags: sharepoint

I have a main list, data received via a form, with multiple columns of data. I'd like to create a child list/editable view with some of these columns + additional columns.

Example
Parent List
ID#, Title, Description, Priority, Contact, Funding,

Child List
[ID#, Title, Priority], Status, Manager, Assigned

The child list would be managed by a different unit, however, the data needs to stay consistent.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Lookup columns in your child list adding the required columns from the Parent list.

**1.** Go to Child List > List Settings > Create Column

**2.** Select column type as Lookup

**3.** Select your parent list in the drop-down just below the "Get information from:" line.

**4.** Select ID column in the drop down below "In this column:" line.

**5.** Check the rest of the columns you want from the parent list below "Add a column to show each of these additional fields:" line.

**6.** Click on OK, now you'll see all the selected columns will be added to your child list.

Please note that adding data to Parent list will not add the data to Child list, instead the user will get a drop-down to select in the Parent:ID field while adding/editing data to child list.

Comment: Hey SlackerAmit, Thanks for the response. Can you clarify your last note. Are you saying that upon the user loading the page with the child list, any new data from the Parent will not show?

Comment: No, it will not. If you add an item to Parent list, it will not automatically add an item to child list. The user has to go and add the items to child list, however while doing so, the user will be able to select only those values for the lookup columns which are present in parent list.